# What is the difference between the CommaIO and Comma7IO classes?

Tags: axapta

There is no documentation in the help file as to the purpose of the `Comma7IO` class, just that it extends the `CommaIO` class.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To support read and write of different
>   formats of external files, MorphX
>   features a range of different Io
>   classes; CommaIo for comma separated
>   files, **Comma7Io for comma separated 7
>   bit files**, BinaryIo for binary files
>   and AsciiIo for plain text files.

[From this link: RE: [Axapta-Knowledge-Village] Somthing cool - IO](http://www.mail-archive.com/axapta-knowledge-village@yahoogroups.com/msg05387.html)

Comment: This is a quote from the "Developing for Microsoft Dynamics AX" help file.

Answer (score 1):

Run this job

```
static void TestComma7Io(Args _args)
{
    str                 testString  = 'ABCDEFG~ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊË~HIJKLMNOP';
    str                 filename    = @"C:\TMP\test1.txt";
    str                 mode        = 'W';
    Io                  io;
    container           con;
    FileIoPermission    perm;
    ;

    perm = new FileIoPermission(filename, mode);

    if (!perm)
        return;

    perm.assert();

    // BP deviation documented.
    io = new Comma7Io(filename, mode);

    if (io)
        io.write(testString);

    CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
}
```

and check the content of the file: "ABCDEFG~*\300\301\302\303\304\305\306\307\310\311\312\313*~HIJKLMNOP". As you see, 8-bit characters have been replaced with their [octal codes](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/ISO-table.html).

If you replace `io = new Comma7Io(filename, mode);` with `io = new CommaIo(filename, mode);` the original string will be written to the file: "ABCDEFG~ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊË~HIJKLMNOP".